# Como fazer um método escrever na variável em que se extende?

Tags: c#

Tive uma idéia para aplicar em loops e queria fazer um método `bool.toogle()` onde a variavel se extende o médodo recebera o valor contrário. Algo mais ou menos assim:

```
bool variavel = true;

variavel.toogle();

//variavel agora possui o valor false
```

Comment: Isso não é possível. `bool` é um *value type*, logo é passado por valor e não por referência. Qualquer alteração dentro do método não é efectivada no valor original.

Comment: Descobri nos meus testes que isto é realmente impossivel em C#, porém em VB.NET funciona usando ByRef

Comment: Em C# também há a possibilidade de passar *value type* por referência, declarando esses parâmetros com *ref* ou *out*, no entanto, nos métodos de extensão, não é permitido fazê-lo no primeiro parâmetro, aquele que é precedido de `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você quer usar [`Extension Methods`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/extension) seria algo assim:

```
using System;

public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static bool toggle(this bool value)
    {
         return !value;
    }
}
```

E pra usar

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        bool variavel = true;
        variavel = variavel.toggle(); // false
    }
}
```

-

Outra solução é passando a referência do objeto.

```
public static void toggle(ref bool value)
{
    value = !value;
}

public static void Main()
{
    bool variavel = true;
    toggle(ref variavel); // false
}
```

Comment: Esta foi a solução mais próxima que encontrei, mas foge do que realmente eu queria fazer que era nao ter que repetir o nome da variavel (variavel = variavel.toggle();)

Comment: @Kaizonaro Fiz uma outra solução, não exatamente com `Extension Methods`, mas faz sem atribuir diretamente.

Comment: Qual seria a outra solução

Comment: @Kaizonaro Eu atualizei na minha resposta

Comment: obrigado, isso ja simplifica bastante

Answer (score 4):

O que podes fazer é simplesmente negar a variável.

```
bool toggle = true;

toggle != toggle; // toggle = false
toggle != toggle  // toggle = true
```

Comment: Cheguei a fazer isto, vi que funciona perfeitamente. o objetivo de criar um bool.toogle() era fazer a  linguagem ficar mais amigavel.

Comment: Já que ninguém respondeu à pergunta, havendo uma resposta aceite deveria ser esta.